# Is there a cleaner syntax for applying an operation to each element of a sequence?

Tags: c#, c#-3.0

```
int z = 1;
double result = Math.Log(z);            //works
```

However trying to do the same thing with an array of numbers doesn't work:

```
int[] z = new [] {1,2,3,4};
double[] result = Math.Log(z);            //Syntax 1 - error CS1503: Argument '1': cannot convert from 'int[]' to 'double'
double[] result = z.Select(p => Log(p)).ToArray();  //Syntax 2 - OK
```

How can I make Syntax #1 work?  Syntax #2 seems dirty to me.

Comment: It sounds like you want to take an array of 'int' and get back an array of the log of each value.  Is that correct?

Comment: yes, it should be {Log(1),Log(2),Log(3),Log(4)}

Comment: Syntax #2 is far from dirty -- almost awesome, in fact

Answer (score 4):

No, there is not a cleaner way.  The **Syntax 2** use of `Select()` and a lambda expression to apply `Math.Log()` to each element is the idiomatic way of of doing this in C#.

Comment: Yup. It's about as clean as you could possibly expect. Admittedly you need a ToArray call at the end or change the type of the result variable, but that's all.

Comment: @Jon: I think Array.ConvertAll is cleaner in this case.

Answer (score 2):

```
int[] z = new [] {1,2,3,4};
double[] result = Array.ConvertAll(z, p => Log(p));
```

or

```
double Log(int i) { return Math.Log(i); }

int[] z = new[] { 1, 2, 3, 4 };
double[] result = Array.ConvertAll(z, Log);
```

Answer (score 2):

For completeness, It should also be noted that one of the biggest stregths of Linq is the ability to extend it.

If this operation is something that you do a lot, it may well be a candidate to extend your IEnumerable with a Log function, this would be very simple

```
  static class LogExtension
  {
    public static IEnumerable<Double> Log(this IEnumerable<int> list)
    {
      foreach (int i in list)
      {
        yield return Math.Log(i);
      }
    }
  }
```

Then simply call it like...

```
IEnumerable<Double> logValues = myInts.AsEnumerable().Log();
```

Answer (score 1):

You could encase the ugliness into a function:

```
private static double[] getLogForIntArray(int[] z)
{
    double[] q = (double[])z.Select(p => Math.Log(p)).ToArray();
    return q;
}
```

and call it for syntax 3 (and return it into something):

```
double[] q = getLogForIntArray(z); // Syntax 3
```

Comment: if only we could use the partial class trick and overload the damn math class as

    static partial class Math
    {
        public static IEnumerable<double> Log(IEnumerable<double> a)
        {
            return a.Select(p => Math.Log(p));
        }
    }

Comment: Unfortunately, I can't get Extension Methods to work with Static classes like 'Math'.  You may have better luck.

Answer (score 1):

This looks the cleanest solution to me:-

```
double[] x = Array.ConvertAll(z, p => Math.Log(p));
```

It ought to be a better solution than select since ConvertAll knows up front how many elements there will be in the returned array.  I'm not sure thats true of select, it could be if there some other compilier magic going on.  However the above is cleaner because the convert intent is more clear.

Comment: Good answer; Array.ConvertAll got a *lot* easier to use in C# 3.0; in C# 2.0 you usually have to specify both generic types, which is a pain. Gotta love the improved type inference. +1

Answer (score 1):

In this code:

```
int[] z = new [] {1,2,3,4};
double[] result = z.Select(p => Log(p)).ToArray();
```

Most, if not all, of the "cruft" you see is due to the use of arrays, when the question title reads "Is there a cleaner syntax for applying an operation to each element of a **sequence**?"

In .NET 3.0, a "sequence" is encapsulated with the `IEnumerable<>` interface.

Using this, you end up with much cleaner code:

```
IEnumerable<int> z = new[] {1, 2, 3, 4};
IEnumerable<double> result = z.Select(i => Math.Log(i));
```

Throw in the use of implicit typing through the **var** keywork and things are very clear indeed:

```
var z = new[] {1, 2, 3, 4};
var result = z.Select(i => Math.Log(i));
```

Generally, you'll find the new features of C# 3.0 (especially LINQ) play most nicely when you use List<> instead of Arrays.

If you have code that is already array based, I'd suggest adding overloads to your API that accept IEnumerable instead of int[], allowing the consuming code to use modern language features.

Answer (score -1):

Not quite sure what you're asking, but...

You could provide an index into the array.

```
for (int i = 0; i < z.Length; i++)
{
  Math.Log(z[i]);
}
```

Though I see no point in not retaining the value of the calculation?

**Edit**

You might have to use the double data type as that is what math.log returns

```
        static void Process()
        {
            double[] test = { 1, 2, 3, 4 };
            double[] answer = new double[test.Length];
            for (int i = 0; i < test.Length; i++)
            {
                answer[i] = Math.Log(test[i]);
            }

        }
```